# gitflow branching strategy with bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

I am trying to implement gitflow branching strategy and trying to understand how to resolve the problem I am facing. if you think there is a better branching strategy which could solve this issue please let me know.

**how to handle parallel releases**

let's consider two team are working on two releases. and each developer created feature branching from develop branch.
feature `f_1` and `f_2` are part of same `release (release_f)`, however `n_2` feature is part of different `release (release_n)` which team_2 is working on it.

```
develop
    --feature/f_1 (team_1/dev_1)
    --feature/f_2 (team_1/dev_2)
    --feature/n_1 (team_2/dev_1)
```

However, while merging into develop. this happened.

```
0.0.1------f_1-----n_1----f2--
```

Now how do I create two different releases such that, `release_f` contains `f_1` and `f_2` or exclude `n_1` as `release_n` is not fully ready to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

While gitflow is commonly used, [many](https://www.oudeis.co/blog/2022/gitflow-considered-harmful/) [people](https://www.endoflineblog.com/gitflow-considered-harmful) [are](https://medium.com/@matt.dekrey/git-how-i-use-it-and-why-i-dont-use-gitflow-8688f255fef2) [criticizing](https://medium.com/@patrickporto/4-branching-workflows-for-git-30d0aaee7bf) it. And for good reasons in my opinion. It is too complex and not adaptable.

So in your case the `develop` branch contains the common base that both releases are bases on. Your strategy will then be to create one branch `release_f` from `develop` where f_1 and f_2 are merged into and another branch `release_n` from `develop` where n_1 is merged into. That's the main core structure.

Then there are the details that only can be answered with specific knowledge of the product itself, e.g. should x_3 and y_5 be merged into `release_f` and/or `release_n` as well? Which of the features from the release branches should be merged into the `develop` branch as well? Should some of the features be possible to enable/disable compile-time with feature flags (e.g. `#ifdef`)? Etc.

So my recommendation is to look (briefly) at gitflow followed by looking into some of the other strategies, and then find what works for you. Start rather simple than complex, you can (and most likely should) always change later.

In my opinion the two key points in a sound branching strategy is the following:

- You have a branch which is tagged every single time a release is made<sup>1</sup>.
- When you need to make updates/bugfixes to a release made earlier you create a maintenance branch from the corresponding release tag.

The rest is details.

---

<sup>1</sup> Notice "a branch", not "one branch". It can be different branch for different releases.

Comment: I agree that gitflow is too complicated. is there any other workflow do you recommend. the problem is develop branch contains `n_1` which should not be there as this feature is planned to release later as part of separate release.